# Elasticsearch - Filter on string array and then aggregate on relevant keywords only

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index with an attribute containing a list of keywords.

Let's say my documents look like this :

```
{
  "product_name": "Iphone",
  "keywords" : ["Best seller", "Apple", "Black", "Awesome"]
}
{
  "product_name": "Galaxy S21",
  "keywords" : ["Awesome", "Android"]
}
```

I want to enable my users to do get autocompletions on the keywords (like suggestions) but I also want to make aggregations on the suggestions to let them know how many documents match each one.

So if a user types "A", we should return 3 results :

```
{"expression": "Android", "count": 1}
{"expression": "Apple", "count": 1}
{"expression": "Awesome", "count": 2}
```

"Best seller" / "Black" should not be returned as results by Elasticsearch.

There's no mapping constraint.

I've tried queries like the one below but unexpected keywords are returned in the aggregations :

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "a",
      "fields": ["keywords"],
      "type": "bool_prefix"
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "matched_keywords": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "keywords",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any solution / advice would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you will have to unwind that array and then aggregate. Also if there is only one field then why use multi_match? Just curious.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @VisakhVijayan, I'm not sure what you mean by "unwind" (I'm not using a nested structure and I don't know if it's a pretty new feature in Elasticsearch). For the multimatch query, you don't have to worry about it since it depends on the mapping. The aim is to filter results based on prefixes (wildcard queries could do the job too if quick enough).